# Why can't whatever UIButton in the bottom left corner of the screen show its highlighted state?

Tags: xcode, uibutton, autolayout, storyboard

Why can't whatever UIButton in the bottom left corner of the screen show its highlighted state?

I added another post a second ago while I was more confused about the issue and quickly got voted down. After more research, I have no clue what is causing this issue still...

The image on the left is what I want to be working, and the one on the right is the closest I have gotten to placing the images in the right spots while they still highlight.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, I have the buttons all aligned closer than the margin to the edge of the screen at 0 points away. All of the buttons correctly show their highlighted state when pressed except for the one on the bottom left. I have placed them inside a stack view, and tried multiple constraint layouts while shuffling the buttons around. Whichever button is on the bottom left won't highlight.

When I say highlight, the 2nd button in the image is highlighted. There is no UIViewController subclass attached to this storyboard view controller. Only the default state has any imagery attached to it (this is all that is normally required to get the darker highlight version automatically), and each button has both a background image and a main image.

Comment: Maybe the button is a Custom button. Maybe `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` is false. Maybe something is in front of the button and eating the tap, or maybe the button is outside its superview so that it is untappable. There are lots of possibilities.

Comment: @matt All the button are custom. I don't want system buttons because I plan on changing the main image in each button and want exactly the image I use. I will add a picture of the closest thing I have gotten to work.

Comment: I will make a demo project with the same issue just for you.

Comment: @matt I copied and pasted the stack view from the left picture into another project, then set the constraints the same, and copied the needed assets. It works in a single view application just fine. I am going to run through some other things. This is really weird! The system button turns the image blue, does it not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138070/discussion-between-sethmr-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

After hurting my brain trying to figure out what was causing the issue I realized that I should have used more troubleshooting techniques before jumping to conclusions.

On my device the bottom left corner of the screen is barely touchable. The phone has had avid use being tested on by myself, and apparently the edges of the screen become less sensitive, especially with a screen protector on.

What I should have done...

1. Test the bug out in a brand new project to ensure that I am aware of the conditions causing the problem.
2. Test the project on a different device or simulator.

After doing both of those, I was guarenteed to find my solution to a bug that was very different than I am used to finding, and I will try my best to always use these techniques on future bugs before bothering all of stack overflow with a problem that they will never be able to diagnose.

Using the simulator revealed that my phone was having issues, and I will replace my phone in a couple weeks while continuing to work on my projects in the mean time!